# sharedpreference value lost of App restart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Shared prefernces value being cleared after app restart...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
prefs.setString("mobileNumber", mobileController.text);
prefs.setString('isAuthenticated', 'true');
var login = prefs.getString("isAuthenticated");
```

Comment: So how are you checking if the values are there at app restart or not?

Comment: I am printing the values in initstate , but it returns null

Comment: @RisheekMittal doesn't matter, He's using mocking which clears the data from shared preference it is not persist

Comment: mocking is a tool of testing like any other testing tool it should be for testing only not for use as a production app

Comment: @providerZ  I remove mocking and it works thanks...

Comment: @providerZ well if she's adding a value checker before this code then the mocking wouldn't matter and she has to check it anyways to make sure that the older data doesn't get overwritten

Comment: @RisheekMittal well she can't check anything cuz there is nothing :)

Comment: @providerZ I understand what  mocking is I just wanted to say that she's adding the values to the prefs so there are actual values being added to the storage so if she's checking if there are values pre-stored and then running this code if the prefs is empty then she doesn't need to remove the mocking